# Typing: How to consider class arguments wrapped with partial?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class MyClass that expects a class parent_cls as an argument which fullfills the interface ParentInterface.

ChildA implements/extends from ParentInterface. Since inside of MyClass, parent_cls is instantiated with the argument a and b, the addtional argument c of ChildA is partially instantiated outside.

In principle this does run in Python. However I get a type warning from Pycharm:
[image]

Any ideas how to fix that type warning?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from functools import partial
from typing import Type, Optional, Callable, cast


class ParentInterface(ABC):
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self):
        pass


class ChildA(ParentInterface):
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int, c: str):
        super().__init__(a, b)
        self.c = c

    def do_something(self):
        print('I am ChildA')


# update 1
class ChildB(ParentInterface):
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int):
        super().__init__(a, b)

    def do_something(self):
        print('I am ChildB')


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, parent_cls: Type[ParentInterface]):
        self.parent = parent_cls(3, 4)

# alternative
# class MyClass:
#     def __init__(self, parent_cls: Callable[[int, int], ParentInterface]):
#         self.parent = parent_cls(3, 4)


def typed_partial(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    return cast(Type[cls], partial(cls, *args, **kwargs))

# original code
# child_a_cls = partial(ChildA, c='some string')
# solution
child_a_cls = typed_partial(ChildA, c='some string')

my_class_with_childa = MyClass(parent_cls=child_a_cls)
my_class_with_childb = MyClass(parent_cls=ChildB)
```

Update:
Added the solution from @a_guest and the alternative Typing with Callable[[int, int], ParentInterface] proposed by @user2357112 supports Monica.

Comment: These classes don't make sense. Both children of `ParentInterface` violate the signature specified for the `abstractmethod`, and making `__init__` abstract is weird in the first place. It looks like what `MyClass` really wants is a callable that takes two ints and returns *something* - maybe anything at all, or maybe an instance of `ParentInterface` if that class turns out to actually have a reason to exist beyond the misguided abstract `__init__`.

Comment: A callable like that would be annotated as `Callable[[int, int], object]` or `Callable[[int, int], ParentInterface]`.

Comment: Did a mistake there. Now ChildB makes sense. Why is making __init__ abstract weird? That way I can prevent ParentInterface from being instantiated if there is no other abstract method.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal with Callable typing. Added that as an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) to force the type checker assume the indicated type:

```
child_a_cls = cast(
    Type[ChildA],
    partial(ChildA, c='some string')
)
```

During runtime this function is a no-op (though still a function call). See also [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#casts).

If you do this often, you could also move it to a separate function:

```
def typed_partial(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    return cast(Type[cls], partial(cls, *args, **kwargs))
```

Answer (score -1):

you can specify the type for `parent_cls` variable like `partial[ParentInterface]`:

```
from typing import Optional

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, parent_cls: Optional[partial[ParentInterface], ParentInterface]):
        self.parent = parent_cls(3,4)
```

you have to keep in mind that [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is a class

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. But if you look at update 1 your solution would raise another type warning.

Comment: Use typing.Optional

Comment: @piveloper check my answer

Comment: I added your proposal with update 2. Unfortunately it does not work